# Customer ArrayList Class amending Specific Element in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, imageicon

How do i change a specific variable at a specific point in a custom ArrayList?  I have created an ArrayList class and need to adjust a certain variable within the list, but i cannot seem to figure how i would achieve it.  I have searched for the answer as well but nothing seems specific to my problem.

The code for my Super Class is:

```
public class Parcel extends JPanel
{
    protected int idNum;
    protected double charge;
    protected char zone;
    protected ImageIcon i;
    protected static ArrayList<Parcel> parcelList;
    protected static ParcelList newParcel = new ParcelList();

public Parcel(int id, char z) 
{
    this.idNum = id;
    this.zone = z;
}
```

And the code for my list is...

```
public class ParcelList extends Parcel
{

ParcelList()
{
    parcelList = new ArrayList<Parcel>();
}

public void addBox(int id, char z, int w, int l, int h)
{
    parcelList.add(new Box(id,z,w,l,h));
}
```

What i am looking to do is change the ImageIcon for example, change the ImageIcon of the 5th element in the List of list that contains many different instances of Box with differing images. And also Removing an element.

Is it possible to do this with the current way i have set my code up?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, did you read [`ArrayList` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

Comment: `ParcelList extends Parcel` and `protected *static* Arraylist...` are almost certainly mistakes

Comment: Yes but its not working for me.  For example i tried changing the idNum of an element using this   `newParcel.set(1, idNum=8);`  and it returned cannot find symbol  method(int, int)

Answer (score 2):

Never minding what seems to be some redundancy in the code, one way to do this is to use `newParcel.get(index)`, modify the `Box` that you get from it using setter methods, then `newParcel.set(index, newBox)`

Comment: Thanks that helps, so i would use the get to grab the data from the `(index)` and then redefine it using `newBox` with the amended data?

Comment: Actually, if you're only modifying the state of the Nth object in the list you do *not* need to use set.  Remember, objects are references, so the list is actually a list of references.  When you get the `Box` and modify it, you're changing the state of the object the reference in the list refers to.  So set is redundant and pointless.

Now, if you are making a *new* `Box` object based on the one you get from the list, then yes, you need to use set to make that new object reference replace the old reference.

Comment: So how would i implement this into code?  As when i am trying to do that at the minute all i get returned is a syntax error saying....  cannot find symbol method(int, int)  the two `ints` being index and new data

Comment: That's hard to say, because you seem to be putting `Box` objects into an `ArrayList<Parcel>`. Nevertheless, assuming that `parcelList` is an `ArrayList` of `Box` objects:

`Box b  = parcelList.get(index);
    b.setIdNum(8);`

Also assuming that `Box` is your own custom class, you use your own setter methods to set the variables.